# Templates and sub Templates aren't working in Nav

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I've got this [app I'm working on](https://github.com/jshultz/real-estate-rails-angularjs/tree/develop). I've got a nav built and it sort of works. But not right. I'm pretty confident I'm screwing this up some where.

The [nav looks like this](https://github.com/jshultz/real-estate-rails-angularjs/blob/develop/app/views/layouts/_navigation.html.erb). The problem is, that it never shows the current view highlighted in the nav (except for dashboard) unless i go directly to that page. But, if I do go directly to the page, none of the angular stuff works? The second problem is, under the Admin menu, I can't get any views to appear. But, if I refresh the page, then I can? That seems odd.

[This is what my routes look like](https://github.com/jshultz/real-estate-rails-angularjs/blob/develop/config/routes.rb). What am I missing?

UPDATE:

Ok, so, if I start from dashboard, then navigate to other pages (such as admin/create or admin/manage) then it doesn't work (except for /properties) and I don't see the view update correctly (again, except for /properties). However, if I start in /properties, refresh the page, I see the content (minus any of the angular stuff), but I can navigate to admin/create and admin/manage. Again, Angular doesn't work, but I can at least navigate and see the rails partials.

UPDATE 2:

So, I figured out my own first mistake. I needed to add the routes into the angular side as well as the rails side. Now, I just need to figure out why highlighting isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `partials` to it's own foler:

example: `app/views/shared/_partial_name.html.erb`

right now, you have the `partials` under the `layout` folder. And my guess is that is causing the rendering problem.

Keep `application.html.erb` as the only file under the `layouts`

then render the partials as `shared/partial_name`

Comment: you mean you are not able to render `navigation.html.erb`? try removing `<header>` from first line of `navigation`. just a guess.

Comment: no, i can render navigation, i just can see create.html.erg or manage.html.erb unless i go directly to the url (domain:3000/admin/create or domain:3000/admin/manage.

Comment: lol, ok, i figured it out. I didn't have the route setup in my angular js file. i had it setup in the routes.rb file, but not in angular. once that was settled i was in business.

Comment: dude, good work. you got at least most of the things figure out. I never used angular. wouldn't have known about the routes issue.